# Has it any disadvantage to use dynamic stylesheet language?

Tags: html, css, less

I have just read about {less}. Do you recommend it?

http://lesscss.org/

https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js

Comment: I think it'd be better if you post an actual question, than links.

Comment: If you know this method, you don't have to fallow the links. It is for that people who don't know what I mean about {less}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are doing it clientside and the use has disabled js, the less css javascript-based
   compiler would not work and no styling would be avaiable to the user. So to ensure it works you have to use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) on the server side.
2. As the dynamic css has to bee compiled it might use extra ressources compared to a static stylesheet, so if you do not have proper caching this could use some extra server time.

Comment: And as a comment use [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), which is easier to integrate into the server side, as there is many serverside implementations in you language of choice